English: (1) You never were./(2) You have never been. / (3) You are never
SEE THE CLIP HERE
In this video, At 00:26 , the man says:

"You are not the youngest member of Parliament. (1) You never
were. So, stop showing off."

Why is the simple past used here?
How about:
(2) You have never been.
(3) You are never/ You never are

The first sentence is about the present. The second sentence is  statement about the past, so it's in the past tense. (2) would OK as well. (3) is wrong.

why not present perfect, but the simple past?

"never" refers to a span of time, so you can say "never were" or "never will be". In the present, you either are or are not something, there's no need for "never".

In this context, what is the difference between (1) You never were and  (2) You have never been.

There's not much difference.

You never were works as a follow-on from You are not XXX. You never have been would be possible in this context, but You have never been... only works as the beginning of a sentence. I can't tell you why, it's just the way English is used.
